# Create or change wav file to Wav, 16000Hz mono

Tags: ffmpeg, wav

I'm merging multiple wav files using following command in ffmpeg:

`-f concat -safe 0 -i /storage/emulated/0/AudioClipsForSpeakerRecognition/1/speaker_1_segments.txt -c copy /storage/emulated/0/AudioClipsForSpeakerRecognition/1/speaker_1.wav`

How can I get the output wav file in 16000Hz mono?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-f concat -safe 0 -i /storage/emulated/0/AudioClipsForSpeakerRecognition/1/speaker_1_segments.txt -ac 1 -ar 16000 /storage/emulated/0/AudioClipsForSpeakerRecognition/1/speaker_1.wav`